# Unable to use firebase cloud message delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As stated in the Error message below, I can't find the delegate property. However I found remoteMessageDelegate instead. I thought perhaps firebase team just renamed it, but in the documentation code sample still call it delegate. Can someone clarify this for me?

***Error***

> Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'FIRMessaging *'

***Code***

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
```

Comment: I just tested using the sample code and was unable to reproduce the issue. I'll see if I can find some other ways to reproduce it, but in the meantime, what version of Firebase and FCM are you using?

Comment: i'm currently using Firebase (3.17.0) and FirebaseMessaging (1.2.3).

Comment: The current version of Messaging is 3.1.2, so I suggest you update the pod. I have a good feeling that'll cure what ails you :)

Comment: thx for your help. I do have 1 more question for you. When is the next video? :)